# VBA How to loop faster? [X < 0.51 Sec]

Tags: excel, vba

Loop Frequency

```
  Dim I As Long
  For I = 1 To 200
```

Loop Intervals (Less Than 0.51 Minute is aborted by VBA?!) [This is the issue here.....]

```
  Dim X As Long
  X = 0.51 
  Dim EndTime As Date
```

Start Loop

```
  For Each Contr In Yard.Controls
```

Set Condition

```
  If Contr.Name = "X" And Userform1.Loop_Textbox.Value = 1 Then
```

Flash 1

```
  EndTime = DateAdd("s", X, Now())
  Do While Now() < EndTime
  DoEvents
  If Userform1.Loop_Textbox.Value = 0 Then Exit Do
  Loop
  Contr.BackColor = &H80000012&
  Contr.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectEtched
```

Flash 2

```
  EndTime = DateAdd("s", X, Now())
  Do While Now() < EndTime
  DoEvents
  If Userform1.Loop_Textbox.Value = 0 Then Exit Do
  Loop
  Contr.BackColor = &H80000012&
  Contr.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
```

Finish

```
  End If

  Next Contr

  Next I
```

Comment: There is missing an explaining text what exactly the issue is and what error do you get. What does *"aborted by VBA"* exactly mean. Please give a better description of what is going wrong.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to flash a textbox on a userform, to be (etched then sunken effect)... so textbox flashes every 0.51 minute... so if I made X < 0.51 the vba ignores flashing the textbox and ends the sub routine... What I am trying to do is to make it flash faster... How to make x < 0.51 (time) thanks

Comment: How to make "Loop Intervals" X in milliseconds (X < 0.51) to flash faster?

Comment: Instead of a date (which is not accurate enough) use the [Timer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, it worked perfectly. Thanks a Million :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date` is not accuracy enough to track that short time periods. Instead use the [Timer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function).

Here is an example that let the selected cell background color blink 11 times (from white to black) with a 0.51 second pause in between:

```
Public Sub Blink()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 10
        Dim StartTime As Single
        StartTime = Timer

        Do While StartTime + 0.51 > Timer 'wait 0.51 s
            DoEvents
        Loop

        If Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Else
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Color of cell A1 changes 11 times.</sup>*